# Is there any way I can use GridSearchCV with RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

My code to improve model is :

```
clf = RandomForestRegressor()
parameters = {'n_estimators': [4, 6, 9],
                  'max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt','auto'],
                  'criterion': ['mse', 'mae'],
                  'max_depth': [2, 3, 5, 10],
                  'min_samples_split': [2, 3, 5],
                  'min_samples_leaf': [2,5,8]
                 }
    
    print("Improving accuracy")
    acc_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)
    print("Running Grid Search")
    grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring=acc_scorer)
    print("Fitting using optimal parameters")
    grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(train_X_g_h, train_y_g_h)
    clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_
    print("Fit the best algorithm to the data")
    clf.fit(train_X_g_h, train_y_g_h)
    print("Running predictions")
    predictions = clf.predict(val_X_g_h)
    predictions = pd.DataFrame({'Result' : predictions})
    print("Getting Accuracy score")
    print(accuracy_score(val_y_g_h, predictions))
```

The error I get is:
*ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous targets*

I read the documentation and I cannot find any support to estimate the accuracy for a `RandomForestRegressor` model

So, is there any way to get accuracy for my model and use it with GridSearchCV?

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric - it is wrong to use it in the context of a regression, which sklearn doesn't allow you to do either

Comment: Since RF calculates mse and mae, is there any way gridsearchcv can work with either of those measures?